# How do i take advantage of NSCoding to convert an object into a NSDictionary ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have an Objective-C class that implements NSCoding. I need to return a representation of an instance of this class in the form of an NSDictionary, where the keys are the property names and the values are the property values.

How do I make this conversion in Objective-C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be straightforward to create an [`NSCoder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html) subclass, whose `encode<thing>:forKey:` methods just stick the `thing`s into a dictionary, which you can then retrieve.

```
@implementation DriisDictCoder
{
    NSMutableDictionary * encodedDict;
}

- (void)encodeDouble: (double)v forKey: (NSString *)k {
    [codedDict addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:v] forKey:k];
}

// etc.

// Custom method
- (NSDictionary *)dictForEncodedObject {
     return encodedDict;
}

@end
```

Then you create an instance of your coder, and send `encodeWithCoder:` to this object you want in a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, this is the approach I ended up taking.

Answer (score 9):

NSObject has a method `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`. From the documentation:

> Returns a dictionary containing the property values identified by each
>   of the keys in a given array.

There's also a corresponding `-setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` method.

NSCoding doesn't actually come in to play here.

Comment: This is not an `NSObject` method; it's from the Key-Value Coding protocol.

Comment: @Jacques Cousteau are you sure? Can a protocol have a implementation? I would say it's implemented in NSObject as well as is might be also overwritten in other foundation objects (like NSArray).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that it's a KVC method. `NSObject` isn't documented as conforming to KVC. There's a chance that it might anyways (it's an informal protocol...). Protocol methods must be implemented by each class if they're not inherited.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the keys for use with that method ?

Comment: @JacquesCousteau, you're right of course, but as with the other KVC methods (`-valueForKey:`, `-setValue:forKey:`), NSObject implements `-dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`. It's easy to understand how such a method could be implemented.

Comment: @driis, there's not a particularly easy, built in way to get an array of an object's keys. I typically implement a method called something like `+keysForCopying` in my class's implementation. It simply returns an NSArray of the keys for properties I want to copy when creating a dictionary representation of the object. You do have to manually keep it up to date when you add new properties to your class...

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a custom NSCoder that writes into a dictionary as suggested in the accepted answer - since I really wanted to re-use the NSCoding implemnentation I already had, and didn't want to maintain another list of properties.

Answer (score 0):

What Andrew Madsen said. If you wanted to use NSCoding though, you would've to encode your object to an NSData object using NSKeyedArchiver an put that NSData in your dictionary. Wouldn't be human-readable though, if that is of concern.
Cheers

Edit: re-reading your question, it's really what Andrew said since you want 1:1 representation of key:values in a dictionary - the NSCoding approach would give you the whole object as value for your dictionary key. So, +1 to Andrew.